# Conflicting errors when login to IOS app using facebook connect

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, dialog, crash

After installing facebook login, we have 2 developers using their own devices (Both using IOS 6.1.2) with conflicting differences.

Developer 1:  Clicks facebook login button, and is redirected to URL to enter facebook login/password- then accept permissions.  The process works.

Developer 2:  Clicks facebook login button, receives permissions dialog in popop (not by url) and does not ask for facebook login/password.  The process crashes every time immediately when click (OK) for permissions.

We have spent a great deal of time on this and would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like Developer 2 has logged into FB in iOS settings, while Developer 1 has not.

That would explain the difference in the login process, though I can't say why iOS-driven FB login would crash but Safari-driven login would not.